# Pylint `--good-names` syntax on Linux

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, pylint

I've been using PyLint in Windows with such configuration:

```
pylint \
    --good-names ('i','el','of','df','pd','Entity') \
    --bad-names ('foo','bar','kek','KEK') \
    module
```

but on Ubuntu, I get an exception while trying to parse good-names arguments `('i','el', ...)`:

```
/bin/bash: -c: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

What is the correct way to provide such uncommon arguments on ubuntu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should enclose your tuples in quotes:

```
pylint \
    --good-names "('i','el','of','df','pd','Entity')" \
    --bad-names "('foo','bar','kek','KEK')" \
    module
```